# How to open ASCII file in WEKA software

Tags: classification, weka

I have converted the .tiff file into ascii format with the help of ArcGIS, now i want to open that same file in WEKA, and it is asking me to open file in .arff format which i am clueless on how to convert ascii file into that, as format for ascii file is  .TXT.

Comment: Would you be willing in trying with R?

Comment: Yes i am willing to learn R and use it for Image classification, could you please suggest on how to go about starting to learn R

Comment: Sorry, I suggested you to try with R, considering that you would know it. You could start at [CRAN](http://cran.r-project.org/).

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to see the issue without some sample data or error message, but it appears that the file can't be read into Weka in its current state.

You could try formatting the dataset to comply with the [Attribute-Relation File Format](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/arff.html).

Failing this, you could also format the dataset into a Comma-Delimited File Format with header information on the first row, and data underneath.  CSV Files are accepted into Weka quite fine.

Hope this Helps!

Comment: i have converted the landsat 5 image into ASCII format with .txt as its extension, and when i try to input that into weka using text converters it gives following error  "invalid stream header"

Comment: Perhaps you could try converting the data to comma delimited and save it as CSV instead.

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are working with satellite imagery and that you know R, you could try something like this:

```
library(raster)
library(foreign)
library(RWeka)

dir.satellite <- '../tiffs' # Folder with your satellite TIF files
# Read them from their full paths
bands <- list.files(file.path(dir.satellite), full.names = T,
                    pattern = '.TIF$')  
stkTIF <- raster::stack(bands) # group them into a rasterStack object
# Write the WEKA arff file
write.arff(as.matrix(stkTIF),
           file = file.path(dir.satellite, 'your_file_name.arff'))
```